# Insert data from session to vue-component

Tags: html, node.js, express, vue.js

In my routes file i am getting the user in the current session and rendering the profile html:

```
  app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.html', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });
```

The profile.html would need the user data to display, for example the user name. The data displayed in the html is specified in a vue component:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },  
  ready: function() {},
  methods: {}
});
```

The corresponding html element would look like this:

```
  <div id="app"> 
    {{ message }}
  </div>
```

My issue is that i don't understand how to put the user data in the vue component? From the vue component, how do i retrieve user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an ajax request to retrieve the user info in the Vue component.

Endpoint:

```
app.get('/user', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.user)
});
```

Component:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    user: {}
  },  
  created: function() {
    // make an ajax request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', '/user')
    xhr.onload = () => {
      this.user = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    }
    xhr.send()
  },
  methods: {}
});
```

Alternatively, you could use a templating engine:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score -1):

Write app in singleton pattern, instance app in vue component, get data.